# odatagen: Failed to generate proxy classes. Please verify the metadata (iOS)

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, wcf, odata

Im working on **[Open Data Protocol (OData)](http://www.odata.org)** which is a standardized protocol for creating and consuming data API's.

**OData** builds on core protocols like `HTTP` and commonly accepted methodologies like `REST` .

I have installed, configured and built **OData**  successfully on **iOS6**

Currently I'm creating a **Proxy class** to connect to the **OData Service** using the following commands:

```
cd /Users/Shamsu/Applications/ODataObjC/ODataSDKV1-1.3/Framework/bin/ODatagenBinary/MacOSX10.7.sdk/Debug

./odatagen /uri=http://35.35.6.4/MyApp.MyApp3D.DataService/MyApp3DDataService.svc/ /out=/Users/Ramshad/Applications/ODataObjC/ODataSDKV1-1.3/Framework/bin/ODatagenBinary/MacOSX10.7.sdk/Debug  /u=sa /p=123
```

However, I'm getting the error: `"odatagen: Failed to generate proxy classes. Please verify the metadata"`

I can see the "metadata.xml" file  is updated as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<edmx:Edmx Version="1.0" xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx">
  <edmx:DataServices m:DataServiceVersion="1.0" m:MaxDataServiceVersion="3.0" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
    <Schema Namespace="MyAppDBModel" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm">
      <EntityType Name="User">
        <Key>
          <PropertyRef Name="UserID" />
        </Key>
        <Property Name="UserID" Type="Edm.Guid" Nullable="false" />
        <Property Name="UserName" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="10" FixedLength="true" Unicode="true" />
        <Property Name="UserDescription" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="50" FixedLength="false" Unicode="true" />
        <Property Name="Active" Type="Edm.Int64" />
      </EntityType>
    </Schema>
    <Schema Namespace="MyApp.MyApp3D.DataService" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm">
      <EntityContainer Name="MyAppDBEntities" m:IsDefaultEntityContainer="true" p6:LazyLoadingEnabled="true" xmlns:p6="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/annotation">
        <EntitySet Name="User" EntityType="MyAppDBModel.User" />
      </EntityContainer>
    </Schema>
  </edmx:DataServices>
</edmx:Edmx> "
```

**Note**: the `metadata.xml` file is located at out param location `(/Users/Ramshad/Applications/ODataObjC/ODataSDKV11.3/Framework/bin/ODatagenBinary/MacOSX10.7.sdk/Debug /metadata.xml)`

I'm unable to identify the issue. Any problem with my **windows WCF service /ODataService configuration/database configuration** ? Permission assigned as * (read,write).

Any help on this issue is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't have time to go into this further at the moment, but looking at the odatagen source code, it seems like the error is probably coming from the XSLT [here](https://github.com/OData/OData4ObjC/blob/master/Framework/src/odatagen/objc_filename.xsl) not being able to transform the metadata document you have.  Sorry I can't dig farther into this right now, but maybe that'll at least give you a starting point for your debugging.

Comment: Did you make any progress on this? I'm suffering from the same problem!

Comment: Just skipped my plan with odata. I have used "REST" client instead.

Answer (score 0):

I looked a bit closer at the XSLT document I linked to in my original comment, and it seems that the odatagen tool hasn't been updated to work with CSDL v3. The version of CSDL (i.e., the format used to serialize the metadata document) is indicated by the xml namespace of the Schema element. In your metadata, that namespace is `http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm`, which indicates CSDL v3.  You can see in the XSLT document [here](https://github.com/OData/OData4ObjC/blob/master/Framework/src/odatagen/objc_filename.xsl) that this namespace isn't recognized by the odatagen tool.

Since the odatagen tool is open source (see the source [on github](https://github.com/OData/OData4ObjC)), you can try to tweak the code and XSLT files to make it work for your situation. You could try to just add the v3 namespace to the recognized schema namespaces, and if your metadata doesn't use any v3 features, I would imagine it would just work. Off the top of my head I'm not sure of the exact differences between v2 and v3, so I can't immediately say whether the metadata you've posted above would be valid in CSDL v2.

Alternatively, you could try to generate the $metadata document so that it's using CSDL v2 instead.

Sorry I don't have a better answer for you. Unfortunately, the odatagen tool has fallen a bit behind. But you're more than welcome to contribute to the project :)

Comment: For me the main reason I switched to V3 over that of V2 is to get the inherited sub-type support. I fear that I'd need a proper implementation of the V3 features for this library to be worthwhile to me. Thanks for your points.